# What is this indoor plant which has dark green leaves that curl up and over as they grow?

Tags: identification, houseplants, containers

I want to identify this potted indoor plant. It has dark green leaves that curl up and over as they get longer.

I want to know how to take care of it, since the plant has not grown since I got it. The plant is probably 5 years old.

I'm located in Quebec, Canada and the plant *might* be from the same place as a Dracaena.

[image: Plant to identify]

Comment: It seems that identification questions are on-topic, which is awesome :). If anyone needs any more information I can provide to the best of my knowledge. It's my first question here, so I hope this enough.

Comment: Hi Marc-Andre! Plant identification questions are on-topic and welcome! I encourage you to read the full [identification tag information](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/identification/info) page.This is a great start, and I made some changes according to the instructions in that description. The most important thing to add is location. We'll always ask for it! Edit it directly into the question.  You gave us great information. We just need a bit more. If you need any help here, just let us know!

Comment: @Sue I can only guess the region the plant came based on the other plant I received, I can mention where I am, but since it's an indoor plant does it matter?

Comment: That's a good point. Adding the general location of the plant does help, but may not be as important when it's a houseplant. I'd have to take a look at some of the other houseplant identification questions, of which we have a bunch! You can check them out too. Location might matter in terms of how to care for it, though, but that probably depends on other factors. You can always wait for us to ask for more details if we need them!

Comment: @Sue There I added what I think could help. I'm not in a hurry so I will wait for more questions from people over here. Thanks for your help it is really appreciated :).